# WPF listbox trigger on empty change default style

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a part of code that makes it so every listbox in my application shows a message when empty.

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorBrush}"
                                   TextAlignment="Center" Text="Geen data beschikbaar" Width="Auto" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When I run the application with it enabled (uncommended) the empty listbox indeed display the message.

But when they are filled the item template is wider than it should be.

This is an example where I use a listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="DataGridTraffic"
             Grid.Row="1"
             SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TrafficJams}"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
             SelectedIndex="-1"
             ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource TrafficJamDataTemplateShort}"
             AlternationCount="2"
             BorderThickness="0"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MainListBoxStyle}" />
```

Does anyone have a clue on what is going on?

Edit:

[image: Here is it to wide]

[image: This is how it supposed to be]

The first image shows how it is when I enable the trigger.

The second shows the way it is supposed to be.

**Edit:**

Here is some more as asked for.
This is the Datatemplate for the same thing as the pictures.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BusDeparturesDataTemplateShort" DataType="{x:Type model:BusDeparture}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorLighterBrush}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DelayText}" Value="">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
        <Grid Margin="4,8,4,4">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       FontSize="32"
                       Text="{Binding Path=DeparturePlatform}"
                       Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PlatformChanged}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorBrush}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PlatformChanged}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                TextBlock.FontSize="18"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ServiceNumber}" Width="45" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Destination}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                TextBlock.FontSize="16"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DepartureTime, StringFormat=HH:mm}" Margin="0,0,4,0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DelayText}" TextAlignment="Right"
                                   Foreground="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorBrush}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                TextBlock.FontSize="16"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Carrier}" TextAlignment="Right"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the part where the listbox is in:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <materialDesign:Card Margin="8" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth2" x:Name="CardTrain">
        ...
    </materialDesign:Card>
    <materialDesign:Card Margin="8" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth2" x:Name="CardBus">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock Text="Bustijden" Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueDarkBrush}"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="36" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
            </Border>
            <ListBox x:Name="DataGridBus"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BusDepartures}"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                     SelectedIndex="-1"
                     ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource BusDeparturesDataTemplateShort}"
                     AlternationCount="2"
                     BorderThickness="0"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MainListBoxStyle}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </Grid>
    </materialDesign:Card>
    <materialDesign:Card Margin="8" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth2" x:Name="CardTraffic">
        ...
    </materialDesign:Card>
    <materialDesign:Card Margin="8" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth2" x:Name="CardTwitter">
        ...
    </materialDesign:Card>
    <materialDesign:Card Margin="8" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth2"
                         x:Name="CardNews">
        ...
    </materialDesign:Card>
</Grid>
```

Comment: what do you mean with "wider"?

Comment: The listbox is inside a materialdesign:card and when not enabled the items have the same width as the card. When enabled it the listbox gets an scollbar and the items are bigger then the card's width

Comment: so you have to play with it and fit the width, no?

Comment: The screen has multiple cards which can be enabled and disabled by an admin. When there are less cards the content should scale with it.

Comment: If you set a fixed font size, is normal that it could go out of the limit

Comment: Removing font size does not solve the problem. didn't think it whould because it works when no trigger is present.

Comment: `Width="Auto"` so it gets wider, I guess you are overriding this `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`

Comment: Isn't the solution either. Added that for debuging

Comment: try and failure, check which option is giving you the problem, sorry couldn't help you more

Comment: Can you show more XAML, particularly the ListBox parent? My guess is the parent control is limiting the ListBox width, but the textblock in the trigger is wider than this, resulting in the horizontal scrollbar. Try adding either `TextWrapping="Wrap"' or 'TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"` to the trigger's TextBlock and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: It would also be useful to see the XAML for the listbox's 'ItemContainerStyle' and 'ItemTemplate', as one of these probably has a `width` somewhere that is preventing the horizontal scrollbar from appearing in the second screenshot.

Comment: The textwrap or texttrim did not work. I edited the question to have more code. Hope you can help now